# Sticky footer work but not on my template?

Tags: css, xhtml, footer, sticky

ok, my problem is Sticky footer code work, I've tested it:

No image just copy and paste it will work:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Sticky Footer</title>
<style type="text/css">

* {margin:0 auto;
padding:0px;}

html, body {height: 100%;}

.wrapper {min-height: 100%;
height: auto;
height: 100%;
margin: 0 auto -250px;}

.footer, .push {height: 250px;}

.footer {background:#CCC;
width:100%;}

.conver {width:960px;
height:200px;}

.extra1 {float:left;
width:320px;
height:170px;
background:#0F0}

.extra2 {float:left;
width:320px;
height:170px;
background:#00F}

.extra3 {float:right;
width:320px;
height:170px;
background:#F00}

.clear {clear:both;}

.footer_note p {font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
font-size:12px;
color:#000;
text-align:right;
padding-top:20px;}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="wrapper"><!-- Wrapper goes around all the content -->
<p>Your website content here.</p><!-- All your content goes here -->
<div class="push"></div><!-- Push the footer to the bottom -->
</div><!-- Wrapper ends here -->

<div class="footer"><!-- Wrap the footer -->

  <div class="conver"><!-- Contain footer elements -->
    <div class="extra1"></div>
    <div class="extra2"></div>
    <div class="extra3"></div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div class="footer_note"><p>Copyright should be here<br/>Company name</p></div>
  </div><!-- conver Ends here -->


</div><!-- Footer ends here -->

</body>
</html>
```

so here it is on my template (looks weird without the images):
PS: there is no image but the template ends like 30px after the text:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>test</title>
<!--[if IE 6]>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://www.google.com.br">
<![endif]-->
<style type="text/css">
/* General */
* {margin:0px auto;
padding:0px;}

p {font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
font-size:12px;
letter-spacing:1px;
line-height:18px;
text-align:left;
color:#000;}

.breadcrumbs_here {width:940px;}

/* background */
html {background:#039 url(../images/bg_repeat_x.png) repeat-x;
height:100%;}

body {background:url(../images/Glare_01.jpg) no-repeat top center;
height:100%;}

html > body {min-height:100%;
height:auto;}
/* background ends here */

/* header */
a#header {background:url(../images/header-trans.png) no-repeat;
display:block;
height:130px;
width:630px;
text-indent:-9999px;
margin-right:500px;}
/* header ends here */

/* sheet starts here */
.sheet {position:relative;
width:1000px;
top:10px;}

.top_sheet {width:1000px;
height:20px;}

.tl {float:left;
background:url(../images/sheet_top_left-trans.png) no-repeat;
height:20px;
width:20px;}

.tm {float:left;
background:url(../images/sheet_top-trans.png) repeat-x;
height:20px;
width:960px;}

.tr {float:right;
background:url(../images/sheet_top_right-trans.png) no-repeat;
height:20px;
width:20px;}

.middle {position:relative;
background: url(../images/sheet_middle.png) repeat-y;
width:1000px;}

bottom_sheet {width:1000px;
height:30px;}

.bl {float:left;
background:url(../images/sheet_bottom_left-trans.png) no-repeat;
width:20px;
height:30px;}

.bm {float:left;
background:url(../images/sheet_bottom-trans.png) repeat-x;
width:960px;
height:30px;}

.br {float:right;
background:url(../images/sheet_bottom_right-trans.png) no-repeat;
width:20px;
height:30px;}
/* sheets end here */

/* Top menu and search */
.top_menu {position:relative;
width:960px;
height:51px;}

.top_menu_inside {float:left;
width:720px;
height:51px;
background:url(../images/menu_bg.png) repeat-x;}

.search_background {float:right;
width:240px;
height:51px;
background:url(../images/search_bg.png) repeat-x;}
/* Top menu and search ends here*/

/* highlights */
.highlights {position:relative;
width:960px;
height:150px;
background:url(../images/highlight_bg-trans.png) repeat-x;}

.hl1{float:left;
height:150px;
width:320px;}

.hl2{float:left;
height:150px;
width:320px;}

.hl3{float:right;
height:150px;
width:320px;}
/* highlights ends here */

/* content */
.content {position:relative;
width:1000px;
background:url(../images/content_middle.png) repeat-y;}

.content_wrapper {position:relative;
width:960px;}

.left {float:left;
height:100%;
width:25%}

.left p {padding-left:10px;}

.right {float:right;
height:100%;
width:75%}

.right p {padding-left:10px;
padding-right:10px;}

.clear {clear:both;
clear:both;
height:0;
font-size: 1px;
line-height: 0px;}
/* content ends here */

/* footer */

.wrapper {min-height: 100%;
height: auto;
height: 100%;
margin: 0 auto -250px;}

.footer, .push {height: 250px;}

.footer {background:#CCC;
width:100%;}

.conver {width:960px;
height:200px;}

.extra1 {float:left;
width:320px;
height:170px;
background:#0F0}

.extra2 {float:left;
width:320px;
height:170px;
background:#00F}

.extra3 {float:right;
width:320px;
height:170px;
background:#F00}

.clear {clear:both;}

.footer_note p {font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
font-size:12px;
color:#000;
text-align:right;
padding-top:20px;}

</style>

</head>
<body>

<a id="header" href="http://www.google.com.br" title="google" target="_self">google</a>
<div class="wrapper"><!-- Wrapper goes around all the content -->
<div class="sheet">

  <div class="top_sheet">
    <div class="tl"></div>
    <div class="tm"></div>
    <div class="tr"></div>
  </div>

    <div class="middle">

      <div class="top_menu">
            <div class="top_menu_inside"></div>
            <div class="search_background"></div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
      </div>

              <div class="highlights">
                <div class="hl1"></div>
                <div class="hl2"></div>
                <div class="hl3"></div>
                <div class="clear"></div>
              </div><!-- highlights ends here -->

      <div class="content">

        <div class="breadcrumbs_here"></div>
            <div class="content_wrapper">
            <div class="left"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed ante ligula, faucibus ut aliquam ut</p></div>
            <div class="right"></div>

            <div class="clear"></div><!-- keeps the floats in one piece -->

      </div><!-- content wrapper ends here -->

      </div><!-- content ends here -->

    </div><!-- middle ends here -->

  <div class="bottom_sheet">
    <div class="bl"></div>
    <div class="bm"></div>
    <div class="br"></div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>

</div><!-- End of the sheet class -->

<div class="push"></div><!-- Push the footer to the bottom -->

</div><!-- Wrapper ends here -->

<div class="footer"><!-- Wrap the footer -->

  <div class="conver"><!-- Contain footer elements -->
    <div class="extra1"></div>
    <div class="extra2"></div>
    <div class="extra3"></div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div class="footer_note"><p>Copyright should be here<br/>Company name</p></div>
  </div><!-- conver Ends here -->


</div><!-- Footer ends here -->
</body>
</html>
```

I'm being sincere here, I don't fully understand how the "sticky footer" works maybe if I knew I would be able to solve this.

The "sticky footer" is sticking to end of the template! I could use absolute postion to make it work bu IE7 hates that...

This template is not supposed to work on IE6, so don't even worry about that garbage...

Answer (score 1):

In the second example, your CSS entry of:

```
* {margin:0px auto;
padding:0px;}
```

Is causing your large space at the bottom of the page.  Is that what you are seeing that is causing it not to work for you?  If you are using Firefox you can get the Firebug plugin ( http://getfirebug.com/ ) which allows you to view and alter the CSS of elements in realtime.  Very helpful debugging tool.